# How to implement transaction in Loopback 4

Tags: loopback, loopback4

I am making two repository calls to update the data in two different tables in db. I want to implement a transaction. Need help on how to perform this.
https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Using-database-transactions.html
From the documentation it looks like transaction can be performed in only one repository not between two repositories.

```
const created = await repo.create({title: 'Groceries'}, {transaction: tx});
const updated = await repo.update(
  {title: 'Errands', id: created.id},
  {transaction: tx},
);

// commit the transaction to persist the changes
await tx.commit();
```

But I want

```
const created = await repo1.create({title: 'Groceries'}, {transaction: tx});
const updated = await repo2.update(
  {title: 'Errands', id: created.id},
  {transaction: tx},
);

// commit the transaction to persist the changes
await tx.commit();
```

Anyone has any idea how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> const created = await repo1.create({title: 'Groceries'}, {transaction: tx});
> const updated = await repo2.update( {title: 'Errands', id: created.id},{transaction: tx}, );
>
> // commit the transaction to persist the changes await tx.commit();
> ```

Yes it is possible, if your repo1 and repo2 belongs to same datasource.

more information [here](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/2614)